# USFS Fusion software bare-ground DTM input

Tags: dem, fusion, canopy-height-model

I downloaded 1-m 3DEP dem from USGS to use as input for Fusion bare-earth DTM ([description here](https://data.usgs.gov/datacatalog/data/USGS:77ae0551-c61e-4979-aedd-d797abdcde0e)) and I'm using USGS lidar data for the point cloud to make a **Canopy Height Model**. Due to data size limitations, I'm running into difficulty trying to input the downloaded files into fusion. The .laz files for the point-cloud really slows down (and even crashes) fusion software when I try and load them in.

Is it better to mosaic the .laz files together to get a CHM of the entire area of interest, or am I limited by the data size to keep them at the smaller cell extent and as individual files?

Comment: Welcome to GIS SE. As a new user, please take the [Tour] which emphasizes the importance of asking One question per Question. Please [Edit] your Question.

Comment: Thanks @Vince for the directions.